# MVC6 Ajax POST - file's processed but view is not being returned even with data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX POST which posts a CSV file and string. This is received. I then process this data and insert the details into the database - success. It returns those records that were new as an object back as the return value - this is also the model used in the view - success.

I then try and send this back as the return and nothing happens to the view.. its not updated.

I have looked for this in other posts - a few PHP and some indications that if you use an Ajax POST the HttpPost result wont work.. however this works fine when you use the normal form submit but its not working with an Ajax post.
Here are my controller actions:

```
        // GET: /SuburbsAndPostcodesAdminController/
    public IActionResult FileIndexView()
    {
        var InitialDisplayView = new NewSuburbsAndPostcodesImported
        {
            Message = "Nothing imported yet.",
            SuburbAndPostcodesImported = null
        };

        return View("FileIndexView", InitialDisplayView);
    }


        // POST: /SuburbsAndPostcodesAdminController/Index
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FileIndexView(CSVFileUploadViewModel CSVFileUpload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Process the file
            NewSuburbsAndPostcodesImported FileProcessed = _service.ProcessCSV(CSVFileUpload);

            return View("FileIndexView", FileProcessed);

        }
        return View();

    }
```

I have a breakpoint on the "return View("FileIndexView", FileProcessed);" and FileProcessed has the correct data in it.

The CSHTML file is:

```
@model ProgressBar2.ViewModels.NewSuburbsAndPostcodesImported

@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Suburbs and Postcodes Upload page";
 }
 ...

 <div>
<h4>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Message)
</h4>
</div>
@if (Model.SuburbAndPostcodesImported != null)
{
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>
            ...
        </th>
        <th>
            ...
        </th>
        <th>
            ...
        </th>
    </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.SuburbAndPostcodesImported)
    {...
```

EDIT Here is the AJAX POST function:

```
        $('#SubmitFile').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // <------------------ stop default behaviour of button

        //var fileUpload = input.files[0];
        var url = "/SuburbsAndPostcodesAdmin/FileIndexView";
        var connId = $.connection.hub.id;
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('File', $("#txtFileUpload")[0].files[0]);
        fd.append('connId', connId);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

        });
    });
```

Why wont this update the view?

What do I have to do to make sure the view updates and the list renders?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are making the AJAX call and *updating* the view in the success callback? Also shouldn't you be returning a partial view?

Comment: I've added the Ajax call. I suspect it needs a view component however I found that it did update when I was just using the submit form. I am thinking there is a problem when I do an Ajax post and maybe others have identified the correct way to do this using Ajax...

Comment: You simply never subscribed to the `success` callback of your AJAX request in order to update the DOM. This works when you submit a form without AJAX because in this case the entire page is reloaded. The whole point of AJAX is to be able to make HTTP requests to the server without reloading the whole page. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AJAX call you never seem to handle the success condition where you are supposed to update the relevant portion of the DOM with the result returned from your controller action. Here's an example how you could handle this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(result) {
        // The result variable here will contain the response
        // body from the controller action. Here you could use it
        // to update the respective portion of the DOM
        $('#someContainerId').html(result);
    }
});
```

This assumes that you have wrapped the portion you want to update with some div element with `id="someContainerId"` and that your controller action returns a PartialView that will contain only the relevant section.

Comment: So when my view returns its handled by the success function in ajax? wondering how I use "result"... is it my model..

Comment: No, it's not the model. It's whatever the POST controller action has returned. It could be HTML. That's why I suggested your controller action to return a PartialView. So that you can directly inject this partial HTML into the relevant section of your DOM.

Comment: Thanks Darin... will refactor using your advice.